# Is it possible to generate individual lock files in a yarn monorepo

Tags: monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarn-lock.json

We are setting up a new app, and we'd like to use a yarn monorepo. Each package in the repo is it's own app. We'd like to be able to deploy each app individually instead of the whole code base to each apps environment. However, yarn workspaces use a single lockfile at the root. What I'm looking for is a way to generate a lockfile in each app's subfolder. So when the deploy runs it can install from a lock file instead of the package.json.